# $\mathbb{E}(\frac{X^2}{X^2+Y^2})$, X and Y are iid from standard normal distribution?

Tags: probability

The most simple solution is the use of symmetry.

$\mathbb{E}(\frac{X^2}{X^2+Y^2})=\mathbb{E}(\frac{Y^2}{X^2+Y^2})$

$
\mathbb{E}(\frac{X^2}{X^2+Y^2})=\frac{1}{2}(\mathbb{E}(\frac{X^2}{X^2+Y^2})+\mathbb{E}(\frac{Y^2}{X^2+Y^2}))=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}(\frac{X^2+Y^2}{X^2+Y^2})=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}(1)=\frac{1}{2}
$

While, I want to know any other solution?

Answer (score 6):

Since $X^2, Y^2$ are   chi square independent, $\frac{X^2}{X^2+Y^2}\sim \beta(1/2,1/2).$

Answer (score 1):

The PDFs for the standard normal distribution yield a double integral which factors in polar coordinates:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X^2}{X^2+Y^2}\right]
&=
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2-y^2/2} \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy \\
&=
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2\theta\, d\theta \int_0^\infty r e^{-r^2/2}\,dr
\end{align}
The $r$-integral evaluates to $[-e^{-r^2/2}]_0^\infty=1$, whereas the double-angle identity yields the $\theta$-integral as

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1+\cos2\theta}{2} d\theta =\frac12\left[1-\frac12 \sin2\theta \right]_0^{2\pi}=\pi.$$
Hence the expected value is indeed $1/2$. The symmetry argument could also be used to handle the $\theta$-integral: $$\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^2\theta\,d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^2\theta\,d\theta=\frac12 \int_0^{2\pi} (1)\,d\theta=\pi$$ where the first equality follows from periodicity and the substitution $\theta\to \pi/2-\theta$.